# Inset faces not working as it had been a few moments ago

Tags: modeling

A few moments ago, inset faces simply created a new face inside another face as it always did. Now, either this happens (*see picture 1*) or the border between the new face and the old one is disproportionate (*see picture 2*). Any ideas what the problem could be?

[image: Picture1]
[image: Picture2]

Comment: it's not clear what you're trying to do on the first picture, could you please share your object? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 2):

Your topology is not good, you have overlapping faces and vertices, if you move your face up and move some vertices you can see that it's not a quad but an ngon, you can inset an ngon but in your case it quickly creates overlapping.

Oh and as pointed out by Csarb3d, you need to apply your scale, it will fix the second point.

[image]

Comment: @Pnyx don't add thanks as a comment, upvote the answer instead. If you feel it completely solved your problem consider marking it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

This might be caused by an uneven scale, check you apply Scale with ctrl+a and then try again.

Comment: Ok, thank you! But, that fixed picture 2, not picture 1.